# How to upload Google Earth kml file to Geoserver (via API or python package) without losing any data or style

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, kml, geoserver-rest-api

I have Google Earth Pro Desktop App where I created placemarks, lines, polygons, and applied individual styles to them. However, I am facing difficulties uploading this data to GeoServer using the geoserver-restconfig Python package. I attempted to convert my KML file to a zip file containing shapefiles, but I could only convert the placemark data without preserving the styles. I am seeking a solution to upload my data to GeoServer while preserving the styles. Alternatively, I am open to uploading the data and styles separately and connecting them using Python code, instead of performing manual operations.

Comment: GeoServer has its own mechanisms for linking data with styles.  Shapefiles don't hold any styling information, you might try geopackages instead

Comment: GeoServer does not support the styling from any data layer, you need to convert your style to SLD and upload that, have you looked at qgis or GeoStyler?

Comment: But I only have an exported kml file, how can I separate the styles from the kml data and load them separately, but I need a mechanism using it, I can connect my data to my styles. but I don't want to do it manually in Geoserver, do you know any solutions for that.

Comment: As mentioned SLD is the style for geoserver, qgis can create them. https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/qgis/index.html

Comment: As I said on your other question, there's no way to do this at present